# Highchart, is there a way to change its data and name of this chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this original chart [in this jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/b72e0vh4/8/) showing the codes for highchart stacks. My goal is to change the data and name of the chart just pressing the button, but I have error showing `Cannot read property '0' of the undefined` after what I did in [this edited jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ox96kbjL/). I have no idea why it cannot read at `key->0`

**EDIT**

The attempted code...

```
$testChart = $('#container').highcharts(options);

$('#setnew').click(function(){
$.each(newData, function(key, val){
  $testChart.series[key].update(val); // gives error, `Cannot read property '0' of the undefined`
});
});
```

Comment: Please do not simply add links to your code, instead, post it in your question. If those links go away, your question becomes useless to future readers.

Comment: my bad, i will edit my question now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong reference to your chart, you should do it in this way:

```
  testChart = Highcharts.chart('container', options);

  $('#setnew').click(function(){
    $.each(newData, function(key, val){
      testChart.series[key].update(val);
    });
  });
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jw6sb2z1/

Comment: oh wow it works, but the `2014` and `2015` label is disappeared upon clicking the button...if you wondering the wheres the label are, its above the name of the fruits

Comment: Hi learnprogramming, It is caused by empty series, which is assigned to the first axis: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vxo9b2nk/